# On using "such probability"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles, grammaticality-in-context

I apologise about the proof-reading-like questions which annoy some of the experts here. But from them, I learn and apply in future. I have the following sentence:

> There is a small probability that something bad will happen. To get an
>   insight on such probability

Is it:

> on such probability

or

> on such a probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these is grammatically fine.

In this context, however, I don't think I'd use *such* at all. You're not speaking about a probability ***like*** that one, which is what *such* implies—you're talking specifically about that particular probability, the probability that something bad happens. And that's what I'd say:

> There is a small probability that something bad will happen. To get an insight on that probability . . .

Answer (score 0):

Many times, ELLers try to use the word such as you have done.

Very  often, it's better to use to phrase it like this:

[...] to obtain or gain insight into a probability **such as that/this/**.

**Such a probability** works better at the beginning of a sentence:

Such a probability [previously defined in another sentence] is not a likely scenario.

for quick reference: rather than use "such a [noun]",it's better to use: a/an [noun] such as this/that/these/those.

A probability such as this is not a likely outcome.